# Android - Metawear - MbientLab - Unable to download Logged Data

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to store data to device memory and retrieved the data later whenever required.
I followed the documentation for data logging.
I am able to log data successfully but when I use the downloadAsync method it just gives me the progress of how many entries I have downloaded and how many are remaining but it doesn't give me the data. And also it tells me that data is downloaded. But I didn't get the data.

There is some discussion but this also doesn't help me a lot.
https://mbientlab.com/community/discussion/2110/trouble-logging-data

below is the logging documentation link
https://mbientlab.com/androiddocs/latest/logging.html

```
// download log data and send 100 progress updates during the download
logging.downloadAsync(100, new Logging.LogDownloadUpdateHandler() {
    @Override
    public void receivedUpdate(long nEntriesLeft, long totalEntries) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "Progress Update = " + nEntriesLeft + "/" + totalEntries);
    }
}).continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<Void>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Void> then(Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "Download completed");
        return null;
    }
});
```

and in the above snippet how can I get the downloaded logged data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stumbling everywhere atlast found a solution,

The above snippet downloads logs, but actually you have to log the logs like when streaming. Below is the complete code

```
 private Logging acceleroLogging;
 private void setupAccLogging() {
    accelerometer = board.getModule(Accelerometer.class);
    acceleroLogging = board.getModule(Logging.class);
    accelerometer.configure()
            .odr(50f)
            .range(8f)
            .commit();
    accelerometer.acceleration().addRouteAsync(source -> source.log((data, env) -> {
        Acceleration value = data.value(Acceleration.class);
        Log.d("LoggingAccelero", value.x() + "::" + value.y() + "::" + value.z());
    })).continueWith(task -> {
        acceleroLogging.start(true);
        accelerometer.acceleration().start();
        accelerometer.start();
        return null;
    });
}
```

and for logs:

```
 acceleroLogging.stop();
            acceleroLogging.downloadAsync(100, (nEntriesLeft, totalEntries) ->
                    Log.i("Logging@", "Progress Update = " + nEntriesLeft + "/" + totalEntries)).continueWith((Continuation<Void, Void>) task -> {
                if (task.isFaulted()) {
                    Log.e("Logging", "Error occured");
                } else {
                    Log.i("Logging", "Downloaded");
                }
                return null;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

wow fantastic, I'm really trying to do the same thing but for euler's angles, but I haven't been able to do it, can you upload the entire code to use it with euler?

Comment: Also what are arionArray and rawFileService?, i cant use that

Comment: These were my arrays. Ignore them. I removed them from code

Comment: And this is a whole code, I don't understand what you mean by whole code.